# How to iterate through args (name and value) of flask request

Tags: python, flask

Here's my code:

```
#http://silvo/ESPresso.dll/UpdateDevice?DeviceName=BlueForceTag&DeviceMac=&DeviceSerial=ABBF0002&TxCount=4&Lat=-33.751320&Long=18.533993&BattLevel=4.05&RSSI=-94&hdop=1.20&sats=9&interval=600000

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ESPresso.dll/UpdateDevice', methods=['GET'])

def index():
    page_response=""
    for arg in request.args:
        page_response+=str(arg)
    return page_response

app.run()
```

I would like to replace the code in index() to return a text list of all arguments passed in the path with name = value format. e.g. from the example URL at the top:

```
DeviceName=BlueForceTag
DeviceMac=
DeviceSerial=ABBF0002
```

etc.

Currently my code returns

```
DeviceNameDeviceMacDeviceSerialTxCountLatLongBattLevelRSSIhdopsatsinterval
```

and I can't get hold of the individual "name" / "value" properties of the arg object.

I'm obviously missing something fundamental (probably Python related). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flask.request.args() method returns a dictionary like object. Please refer to the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args)

In keeping with this information, your for loop needs to be modified as follows:

```
page_response = ''
for key, value in request.args.items():
    page_response += '{0}={1}<br/>'.format(key, value)
return page_response
```

Or simply:

```
return "<br/>".join(["{}={}".format(*a) for a in request.args.items()])
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood it was something called a MultiDict which I got very little information from. I just changed your result line to page_response += '<br>{0}={1}'.format(key, value)